# JavaFX multicolor background Rectangle

Tags: javafx, colors, drawrectangle

It is possible to have a rectangle with 2 or more background colors? Something like 50% black, 50% red?

I want to make a health bar for showing the remained health. I thought I could make something like:

```
life = 100
width with green color = 99,98,....,0%
width with gray color = 0,1,...,100% (end of game)
```

Comment: Why not just put one rectangle on top of the other and change the top rectangle's width? Or use a `ProgressBar` with appropriate styles applied...

Comment: @James_D Good idea! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a bunch of different ways to do this. I'd probably prefer using the functionality already defined in a `ProgressBar` and using CSS to style it to get the colors you want; or just use a regular `Pane` and use two nested background colors and vary the insets. These and various other options using rectangles etc are shown in the demo below:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TwoColoredRectangle extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // property to change:
        DoubleProperty life = new SimpleDoubleProperty(100);

        // "animate" the property for demo:
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(life, 100)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(life, 0))
        );

        // button to set the animation going:
        Button startButton = new Button("Start");
        startButton.setOnAction(e -> timeline.playFromStart());

        VBox root = new VBox(5);

        // Solution 1. One rectangle on another:
        Rectangle base = new Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 20);
        base.setFill(Color.GRAY);

        Rectangle lifeRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 20);
        lifeRect.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        lifeRect.widthProperty().bind(life.multiply(4));

        Pane solutionPane1 = new Pane(base, lifeRect);
        root.getChildren().add(createSolutionPane("Dynamic rectangle on fixed rectangle", solutionPane1));

        // Solution 2: Two rectangles changing together:
        Rectangle leftRect = new Rectangle();
        leftRect.setHeight(20);
        leftRect.setFill(Color.GREEN);

        Rectangle rightRect = new Rectangle();
        rightRect.setHeight(20);
        rightRect.setFill(Color.GRAY);

        leftRect.widthProperty().bind(life.multiply(4));
        rightRect.xProperty().bind(leftRect.widthProperty());
        rightRect.widthProperty().bind(life.multiply(-4).add(400));

        Pane solutionPane2 = new Pane(leftRect, rightRect);
        root.getChildren().add(createSolutionPane("Two dynamic rectangles", solutionPane2));

        // Solution 3: Green rectangle on gray-styled pane:
        Pane basePane = new Pane();
        basePane.setMinSize(400, 20);
        basePane.setMaxSize(400, 20);
        // gray color will be defined in CSS:
        basePane.getStyleClass().add("base-pane");

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.setHeight(20);
        rect.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        rect.widthProperty().bind(life.multiply(4));

        basePane.getChildren().add(rect);
        root.getChildren().add(createSolutionPane("Dynamic rectangle on pane", basePane));

        // Solution 4: Dynamically-styled pane:
        Pane dynamicPane = new Pane();
        dynamicPane.setMinSize(400, 20);
        dynamicPane.setMaxSize(400, 20);
        dynamicPane.getStyleClass().add("dynamic-pane");
        // make background insets depend on the property:
        dynamicPane.styleProperty().bind(life.multiply(4).asString("-fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 0 %f"));

        root.getChildren().add(createSolutionPane("Dynamically styled pane", dynamicPane));

        // Solution 5: Progress bar:
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        progressBar.setPrefSize(400, 20);
        progressBar.progressProperty().bind(life.divide(100));
        root.getChildren().add(createSolutionPane("Progress bar", progressBar));


        root.getChildren().add(startButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("two-colored-rectangle.css");

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Node createSolutionPane(String title, Node content) {
        VBox vbox = new VBox(new Label(title), content);
        vbox.getStyleClass().add("solution-pane");
        return vbox ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and the stylesheet (`two-colored-rectangle.css`):

```css
.root {
    -fx-padding: 20 ;
    -fx-alignment: center ;
}

.base-pane {
    -fx-background-color: gray ;
}

.dynamic-pane {
    -fx-background-color: green, gray ;
}

.solution-pane {
    -fx-spacing: 5 ;
    -fx-padding: 10 ;
}

.progress-bar {
    -fx-accent: green ;
    -fx-control-inner-background: gray ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a [`LinearGradient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/LinearGradient.html) as fill for the `background`:

```
Region rect = new Region();
rect.setMaxSize(100, 20);
rect.setPrefSize(100, 20);
```

#### Code

```
rect.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,
    new Stop(0.3, Color.GREEN),
    new Stop(0.3, Color.RED)
), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
```

#### CSS

Alternatively you can also do this using CSS:

```
rect.setId("myrect");
```

```css
#myrect {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, green 30%, red 30%);
}
```

---

Both versions fill the first 30% of the `Rectangle` with green and the rest with red (horizontally).

Note that James_D's solution should be prefered. This is only for the sake of completeness.

`LinearGradient` extends `Paint` and therefore you could also assign it to the `fill` property of a `Rectangle` (or any other `Shape`).

Comment: Nice. I should have thought of that one too... Note you can do the same with a `Rectangle` and the fill property, if you want (though a `Region` is probably better). Also note you can create a binding for the background property (or fill property) that depends on a (varying) property.

Comment: `LinearGradient` extends `Paint` and therefore can be used everywhere where a `Paint` is expected, including `Rectangle.fill`. I only used `Region` here, since the question is about `background` and not `Rectangle`s and `Region` is the class containing the `background` property...

Answer (score 1):

From your problem statement, I believe the literal answer to your question above would have to be "No", you cannot fill the background of a rectangle with two different colors. It must be one or the other.

But to achieve the goal implicit in your question, (from James_D's comment) You could paint one rectangle in your first color, and progressively cover it with a second rectangle. Or you could paint two separate rectangles, each with a different color, each with a width that would together fill the entire bar. So at first, the rightmost rectangle would fill the bar 100% and the leftmost rectangle would be 0%. Then the size of each would change, the right to 99% and the left to 1%. And so on.

[JavaFX Rectangle class](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html#Rectangle(double,%20double,%20javafx.scene.paint.Paint))

Comment: You can also have a `Region` (eg a `Pane`) with two background colours, and manipulate the background insets.

Comment: Your beliefs are wrong! There are more `Paint`s in the world than just `Color`...